# Entity Framework Code First Foreign Key issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an EF Code First test app. I want to make one-to-many associations between 3 tables. I want to make a schema which looks like this http://gyazo.com/7a1800230a3838adecaafc5cb6676b25.png. When i launch my app VS says me:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'EducationLevels' on type 'ConsoleApplication2.Employee' is not valid. The foreign key name 'EducationLevelId' was not found on the dependent type 'ConsoleApplication2.EducationLevel'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Here it is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (EmployeesContext context = new EmployeesContext())
        {                
            Profession p = new Profession { Id = 0, NameOfProfession = "myprof" };
            context.Profession.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public enum Sex { Man = 0, Woman = 1 }

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public byte Age { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public int EducationLevelId { get; set; }
    public int ProfessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EducationLevelId")]
    public virtual ICollection<EducationLevel> EducationLevels { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProfessionId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
}

public class EducationLevel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Profession
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameOfProfession { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationLevel> EducationLevel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profession> Profession { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap collection and reference navigation properties (an `Employee` has *one* `EducationLevel` and *one* `Profession`, not many, and an `EducationLevel` has *many* `Employees` and not one, and a `Profession` has *many* `Employees` and not one):

```
public class Employee
{
    // ...
    public int EducationLevelId { get; set; }
    public int ProfessionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EducationLevelId")]
    public virtual EducationLevel EducationLevel { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProfessionId")]
    public virtual Profession Profession { get; set; }
}

public class EducationLevel
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Profession
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```